# jMonkeyEngine Pros and Cons

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl, jmonkeyengine

I want to know some good reasons to use jMonkeyEngine for a Java 3d game development tool instead of just creating a game with LWJGL myself? I want to know a good reason I should choose this tool. Does anyone have a list of pros and cons for me to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pros** (as from their own website http://jmonkeyengine.org/)

- Free, open source
- Multiple platform targets
- Modular design
- Great documentation
- Shader based architecture
- User friendly SDK

**Cons**

- If you're interested in the low level parts of creating a game you're better off starting with LWJGL yourself.
- Some engines make you work a certain way but I'm not sure if jMonkeyEngine does that.

If you're not familiar with OpenGL or game development I would advice you to start with jMonkeyEngine since that's more high level and you will be able to produce quality games a lot faster. LWJGL is not even an ounce object oriented which makes using it in java a bit of a pain in the beginning but it's great when you understand how everything works.

That's just my two cents but everyone has different opinions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it does look interesting and easier to make a game with it. But your saying I should try this first and then once I get familiar with it I will have some familiarity to be able to create with LWJGL.

Comment: Does jMonkeyEngine support Blender models or just (.3ds) and their editor?

Comment: I figured out jMonkeyEngine does support certain exports of Blender.

Comment: Its worth noting that Jmonkey does allow some fairly low level access; eg their [mesh buffers](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:custom_meshes) are pretty similar to VBOs

Comment: Your right, it does support low-level coordinates for quads and other shapes, something to note. Thanks!

Comment: One should note that some features such as geometry/compute shaders, and 3D/4D textures are not supported. Also I've found the forums to be not the...friendliest of places.

Comment: I also noticed this but this is just as a beginner game development tool not making a good video game.